# testing site connection limits

Tags: c#, load-testing, performance-testing

I have just taken on a project created by someone else, It can expect a high volume of people logging in between the hours of 8 and 9am. What I need is a tool that can simulate say 100 logins on a page when i provide a username and password. Is there anything like that?

Comment: Depends on your version of Visual Studio? If you have Premium or Ultimate there are load testing tools. If you have Express or Professional they are not standard.

Comment: I'm using professional :(

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Web Performance Load Tester](http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/free-load-tester-lite.html). The LITE version is free. Disclaimer: I work there.